# Access more than 1 virtual property Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I want to access more than one virtual Entity from the Person entity. I want to achieve the below

```
 public int ClientId { get; set; }
 public virtual Person Client { get; set; }
 public int PartnerId { get; set; }
 public virtual Person Partner { get; set; }
```

Please let me know if anyone know how to define this using the ForiegnKey attribute?

Comment: You should [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
 [ForeignKey("Client")]
 public int ClientId { get; set; }
 public virtual Person Client { get; set; }
 [ForeignKey("Partner")]
 public int PartnerId { get; set; }
 public virtual Person Partner { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, Worked for me. Thanks